# Detect referring link that resulted in an install, upon first launch of an iOS application. Possible?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm using google analytics iOS install tracking. I'm wondering if its possible to detect, upon first launch of an application, the referring link that led to the install.
The reason is so I can determine the percentage of users that create an account within my app, that installed my app by clicking my google ad.

If not, are there any other solutions other than google iOS install tracking that can solve this problem?

Comment: it will be possible with apple´s anayltics in itunes connect, that they announced at WWDC 2014... think they said something about "later this fall 2014" or so but until now it s still not released and no infos when it will be available... Apple...   can t wait to see their analytics because they can and will provide data noone else can... https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#302